# Prevent Activity From closing Android Wear (LG G Watch)

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm running an Android Wear app that after a specific Message (as defined by Google Play Wearable API), will start an activity that runs for 2 minutes. To ensure that the watch stays active, I've set the following settings:

- Set up a WakeLock (tried both full and partial)
- Called `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)`
- Put `android:keepScreenOn="true"` in the View files

The wear application will **still** die randomly if the watch screen is not already on (i.e. bright) before the activity create message is created.

Here's the fun part: This bug *only* exists on the LG G Watch. After extensive testing, the Moto 360 does not exhibit the same bug. It will not turn the screen on when the activity starts, but if the user turns on the screen (by tapping it twice or pressing the side button), it will show the activity's view perfectly.

I've included some code so you can try to reproduce the bug:

Mobile side code to trigger activity creation:

```
            NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes =
                Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();
        for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
            MessageApi.SendMessageResult result;
            Log.d(TAG, "Started message sending process.");
            //START_TRAINING = "/start-training"
            result= Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                    mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), START_TRAINING, null).await(); //Since I'm calling await() don't run this on UI thread
            Log.d(TAG, "Sent to node: " + node.getId() + " with display name: " + node.getDisplayName());
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: failed to send Message: " + result.getStatus());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message Successfully sent.");
            }
        }
```

Wear-side service code to start activity:

```
//Do this in a class that extends WearableListenerService + declared in Manifest with BIND_LISTENER
    @Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message received for path " + messageEvent.getPath());
    if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(START_TRAINING)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WearTrainingActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplication().startActivity(i);
    }
```

And finally, some code for the activity that's started on the watch:

public class WearTrainingActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private Sensor mGyroscope;
private TextView mPrompt;
private TextView      mProgress;

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

private ArrayList<AccelerationRecord> mAccelerationRecords = new ArrayList<AccelerationRecord>();
private ArrayList<GyroscopeRecord> mGyroscopeRecords = new ArrayList<GyroscopeRecord>();

private AtomicBoolean shouldCollect = new AtomicBoolean(false);

private static final String TAG = "WearTrainingActivity";

private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

private int delay         = 1000 * 120;
private int maxNumRecords = (delay / 1000) * 20;
private int recordCount   = 0;
private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 50000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_training);
    //Easy way to keep watch from sleeping on me
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    mProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtProgress);
    mPrompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrompt);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtProgress);
            mPrompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrompt);
        }
    });
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mGyroscope     = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    //Collect at 20Hz (Once every 50,000 microseconds)
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SAMPLE_RATE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroscope, SAMPLE_RATE);
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connected to phone.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection to phone suspended. Code: " + i);
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error! Connection failed: " + connectionResult);
                }
            })
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();
    new Thread(new CollectTask()).start();
    shouldCollect.set(true);
    Log.wtf(TAG, "Started collecting");
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "MyWakelockTag");
    wakeLock.acquire();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SAMPLE_RATE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroscope, SAMPLE_RATE);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (shouldCollect.get()) {
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        switch(event.sensor.getType()) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                mAccelerationRecords.add(new AccelerationRecord(x,y,z,timestamp));
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
                GyroscopeRecord gyro = new GyroscopeRecord(x,y,z,timestamp);
                Log.wtf(TAG, "Record is: " + gyro.toString());
                mGyroscopeRecords.add(gyro);
        }
        recordCount++;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    //Not used but must be overridden
}

class CollectTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        INFINITY: while (true) { //Labelled loop
            if (recordCount > maxNumRecords) {
                shouldCollect.set(false);
                wakeLock.release();
                Log.wtf(TAG, "Ending stream");
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
                ByteArrayOutputStream baosG = null;
                try {
                    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                    oos.writeObject(mAccelerationRecords);
                    oos.flush();
                    oos.close();
                    //Handle Gyro
                    baosG = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ObjectOutputStream oosG = new ObjectOutputStream(baosG);
                    oosG.writeObject(mGyroscopeRecords);
                    oosG.flush();
                    oosG.close();
                    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
                    byte[] gData = baosG.toByteArray();
                    PutDataMapRequest dataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create("/data");
                    dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putByteArray("/accel", data);
                    dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putByteArray("/gyro", gData);

                    PutDataRequest request = dataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();
                    PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult =
                            Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleApiClient, request);

                    //Vibrate and tell the user to check their phone
                    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vibrator.vibrate(500L); //Vibrate for half a second
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mPrompt.setText("Please finish the training by opening your phone.");
                            mProgress.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                    break INFINITY; //Leave the thread
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Something happened: " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I did not include view code as it is essentially irrelevant here (only a single TextView), but can add it if deemed necessary.

I'm looking for help with a workaround. I've contacted LG but I doubt they'll respond to my message let alone help me fix it.

Comment: Please post your problem to https://plus.google.com/communities/113381227473021565406 for Wayne Piekarski to take a look into it. Also I would suggest preparing sample app on Github so more people can test it. Good job trying so many things before posting!